# C# WPF Encryption

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt passwords using the C# WPF. what is the best algorithm (and easy to implement) to use? and I want some example about how to use it ...

Comment: Do you want one way or two-way encryption? And there are plenty of samples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx where it lists all cryptoproviders in .Net.

Comment: WPF is a UI framework and not related to encryption. 
I suggest you start looking here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/gsparamasivam/cryptencryption11282005061028am/cryptencryption.aspx

Comment: @Mikael Svenson: one way encryption would be fine, as I don`t need to reverse the encryption. I`m thinking of storing the password encrypted in a database then match the stored value with the encryption of the user-typed one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not try to create your own encryption algorithm rather use the cryptography classes provided in the .NET Framework through [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx).

For passwords a good solution is to use a oneway encryption like a [MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx) hash or [SHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx). And when the user enters his/her password you compute the hash and compare it to the stored hash. The advantage of this is that you do not need to worry about how to securely store the key used to encrypt the passwords.

To increase the security of using a one way hash you can apply a salt, this help restrict the effectiveness of certain types of attackes like a dictionary attack etc. I have not read the wiki entry, but I am sure [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) will provide more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I`ve used the MD5 hash before in my graduation project, but I was thinking of a better way of storing passwords.

Comment: @sikas, when it comes to securely storing passwords I am not aware of anything that is "better" than going with a salted hash. Of course you might have other requirements that a oneway hash does not address, if that is the case you should provide some criteria that you need to meet with your password storage solution.

Comment: I`m using access db to store all the data. So the passwords can be stored in a one-way encryption no need to reverse it ... I`ll check the salted hash idea. But do you know if it produce a fixed size string or is it variable sized?

Comment: The salt is added to the password then the combination is hashed, so the final hash is fixed size where MD5 would be 128 bits (16 bytes), SHA1 160 bits (20 bytes) etc.

Comment: Thanks, I think I`m gonna stick to the MD5 as I`ve used it before.